# Why does Rin Nohara have purple stripes on her cheeks?

Tags: naruto

Not much to explain. Why does Rin Nohara have purple stripes on her cheeks?

[image: Rin Nohara]

Comment: Probably for the same reason Kiba has red stripes on his face (never wondered about that one?)

Comment: @Oded i did actually :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely a sign of her clan. Kiba has the red stripes, as does the rest of his family to symbolize clan members. But, it could be just a symbol of her personality or being, as many characters, such as Chouji, Chouza, Hiruzen Sarutobi, Jiraiya, Orochimaru, Itachi Uchiha, Kankurou, Gaara, etc. have their own, which are shown not to be associated with any of the other members of their clan. So take it two ways, it's either a clan symbol, or just a way of having their own style or their beliefs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is a tradition passed down from clan members or affiliations. For example, Jiraya has red markings because of his toad affiliation. Kiba and other Inuzuka clan members before him had markings, resembling/identifying their dog user capabilities.

Rin has them probably because the Nohara clan puts on the purple striped, or it is either because of her use of medical ninjutsu.